# E_ACCESSDENIED (HR 0x80070005) on CryptImportKey call

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography

Have a legacy code with a call to [CryptImportKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa380207(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Recently faced a problem - on some machines code works fine, on some machines (at least on Win7x64 Pro) it returns 0 (GetLastError() returns an E_ACCESSDENIED error).

Don't actually know, what's the problem, and what kind of information can help investigate the problem. Will be provided, if any anyone give an advice.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Even admin user cannot perform this operation in described situation.

We try to do simple workaround - just rename the "ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys" folder and after automatic creating a new one just moved to it content from the old one. Don't now, how perfect is this "solution".

But it works.

UPD. Process runs from SYSTEM user, and it was enough to grant it with generic read/write access to this folder.